# Never ending shell command with execSync()

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, child-process

I build VS Code extension
I have wrapper in a class like this

```
public exec(cmd: string): string {
    try {
        return execSync(cmd, { cwd: this.workspaceRoot }).toString();
    }
    catch (e) {
        return '' + e;
    }
}
```

If in the code I run

```
let tags = this.exec('git tag --sort=-v:refname')
```

I do get a list of tags. Actually, all other commands run also correctly like `git status`, `git config` and other. But as soon as I run this.

```
let res = this.exec(`git push origin ${name}`);
```

It hangs forever. If I pass wrong tag it stops with error, but if I put correct tag, it suspends. I try to `console.log('git push origin ${name}')` and then copy result and run that command in a terminal, it runs correctly.

What can be the reason of a such behavior?

Comment: you sure it is not waiting for user input?

Comment: Yes. If I log that command and run it in the terminal it does not require any user input.

Comment: Try running `strace git push...` to see the last syscall on which it blocks

Comment: It does not hang when I run this commang in terminal. `strace` also works. close(1)                                = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++

Comment: I mean exec it from Node.js and try to retrieve the output

Comment: Run in terminal `node` and then. `exec('git push origin 1.11.2', (e,so,se)=>{console.log(e,so)});` in prints returned object immediately then after some time `null`. And I do not have `>` on the next line like it is finished execution and ready for next node input.

Comment: I meant exec it from Node with `strace`

Comment: same thing, hangs.

Comment: If you just want to execute git-specific commands, you may consider using a library like [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-git) one.

Comment: @mmomtchev thank you, it was indeed authentication.  Somehow VS Code have me authorized in Github, I logged in with that account. So it uses it to run Git commands. But my extension do not use VS Code Git classes, so they do not know auth. I had to authenticate PC with GH CLI for HTTPS and for SSH to add key and it works not both ways.